# How to format numbers to same number of digits, 0-padded?

Tags: java, format

I have several strings of different length

```
"2323"
"245"
"353352"
```

I need to convert them to string of the same size such as:

```
"0002323"
"0000245"
"0353352"
```

How can I automatically add the correct number of 0s in front of each string ?

thanks

Comment: What should happen if the input string is longer than the expected output format?

Comment: you can also count the number of characters/digits in a string and then just append the desired number of values to the front which could be 0 or space or any other character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(src);
String format = "%1$07d";
String result = String.format(format, i);
```

Comment: uhm ok. However src in my case is already a string and not an integer. Should I convert string > int > string ?

Answer (score 5):

Using [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), or `printf` you can format a Number.

Example using DecimalFormat:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000000");
String number = formatter.format(2500);
```

Hope it helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 4):

Or use **[Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)**:

```
String s = "245";
String zeroPadded = StringUtils.leftPad(s, 6, '0');
```

**Reference:**

- [`StringUtils.leftPad(String, length,
  padChar)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29)